# how to hide list content from placement.info file in orchardproject.net

Tags: orchardcms

I have a "Division" that is a container for list of "Brand".  When viewing the detail page for division, I'd like to hide the brands.  I thought I could do this in the placement.info file like this.

```
<Match ContentType="Division">
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
        <Place Parts_Container_List="-" />
    </Match>
</Match>
```

I've tried a bunch of other attribute names in the Place element but no luck. If I put  that field will be removed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would make the **Parts_Container_List** shape to not render at all when viewing Detail display view for Division type and that's correct. But there is no **Parts_Container_List** shape defined anywhere so maybe this is the problem? Or maybe it's your custom shape?

The **Shape Tracing** feature is very useful in such cases as it allows you to view the exact names of currently displayed shapes.

Could you elaborate more on the problem and what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, the shape tracing feature is amazing!  
You are correct, I'm trying to not display the list of *brands* for container *division* on the detail view.  I can't find the name of the part that is the list.  If I select zone [content].content.list the *shape tab* in designer just says *List*.  The model tab says *List Shape*, but I've tried *<Place List="-" />* and that doesn't work either.

Comment: btw - I'm currently using css to hide the part which works fine.